# How to use @Formula (in Hibernate) to refer to the same (current) object

Tags: hibernate, orm, formula

I have this class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DB.APPL_SESSION")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "APPL_SESSION_ID"))})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TableSequence", sequenceName = "DB.APPL_SESSION_SQ")

public class AiSession{

@Formula("(select sum(nvl(budg.AMT_OV,budg.AMT)) from DB.BUDGET budg where budg.APPL_SESSION_ID = APPL_SESSION_ID)")
private LocalDate realSessionStartDate;
```

In the above formula I was working with DB.BUDGET object and with the current object id ( APPL_SESSION_ID). But now I wanted only to work with the next member variable (StartDate) which is in AidApplicantYearSession class

```
@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "START_OV_DT")
private Date overrideStartDate;
```

How should I write a formula that looks like the above on but uses only the object's member variable ? I came up with

```
 @Formula("(select START_OV_DT from DB.APPL_SESSION)")
```

Is that the correct way? The logic for the two formulas is totaly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Formula` is simply inserted into the SQL `select` clause, so that you can use column names in it:

```
@Formula("START_OV_DT")
```

**See also:**

- [5.1.4.1.5. Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e6481)

Comment: Thank you for your response. On the documentation it says  "Sometimes, you want the Database to do some computation for you rather than in the JVM". Which one is more efficient (doing the calculation in the JVM or let the Database do some computation) if it was more complex formula?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I should also use NVL function. Here is how I did it
@Formula("(select  NVL(START_OV_DT,START_DT)") 
Does omitting the select will be the same as keeping it?

Comment: @MatX: I don't think it makes sense to use `@Formula` for computations that easily can be done at the application side. Yes, it should be okay for multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that has the total number of blocks BITX_SESSION.TOTAL BLOCKS

Now I need to calculate the the percentage from another table that has the number of blocks it received BITX_SESSION_DEVICE.BLOCKS_RECEIVED
Both table has session_id to identify the session i need.

The output I need is percentage of blocks received (BLOCKS_RECEIVED/TOTAL BLOCKS*100). Not sure how to write it using Formula.